# Unable to get code coverage for a scala application using Scoverage

Tags: scala, code-coverage, scoverage

I am unable to measure code coverage for my scala application using the tests written in Python. Steps followed to generate the report,

1. Compile the application 
   activator -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -Dsbt.repository.config=./repositories -Dsbt.log.noformat=true clean coverage dist
2. Run the application on port 9002 
   cd target/universal
   unzip sample-app-1.0.zip
   cd sample-app-1.0
   bin/sample-app -Dhttp.port=9002
3. Run python tests against this application
   cd /home/python-tests
   python ./tests/sample_tests/pkg1/
4. lsof -t -i:9002 (Kill the application)
5. activator -Dsbt.override.build.repos=true -   Dsbt.repository.config=./repositories -Dsbt.log.noformat=true coverageReport

Can someone please help me understand if the setup is correct?

Comment: I took `play-scala-starter-example`, added scoverage plugin to `project/plugins.sbt` and run instrumented application in two ways to test it manually:
a) `sbt clean coverage run coverageReport`
b) `sbt clean coverage dist`, go to `target/universal`, unzip and run the application, kill it, return to project root and call `sbt coverageReport`.

In both cases it has worked and I've had proper coverage reports.

Create simple and publish somewhere simple test project. Without that I cannot help you.

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue and fix it. I was not running my tests the right way against my instrumented code